# How to assign new string values in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, switch-statement, calculator

My simple calculator is trying to display the chosen operation of the user. I understand that in C, strings must be declared as 1D char arrays.

```
int a, b;
int oper; //operation number
char operName[15];

printf("\nEnter two numbers: ");
scanf("%d%d", &a, &b);
printf("\nYou entered: %d and %d", a, b);

printf("\nChoose operation:"
        "\n1 = +"
        "\n2 = -"
        "\n3 = x"
        "\n4 = /");
scanf("%d", &oper);
```

The code compiles and runs. But when executing the switch block, it stops working. I'm using switch to choose the appropriate operation name, and assign it to operName (so I can display the chosen operation before I do the actual operation).

```
switch(oper){
    case 1:
        operName == "Addition";
        break;  
    .
    .
    .
    default:
        operName == "Invalid input";
}

printf("\n\nYou chose: %s", oper);
```

I read somewhere that I need to use pointers to prevent memory leaks, but I'm new to this so maybe there's an easier way.

Comment: If you're trying to assign that string literal into operName , use strcpy(), strncpy(), strlcpy() or memcpy()

Comment: The statement *"... I need to use pointers to prevent memory leaks..."* on its own makes no sense;  pointers are not some magic mechanism to prevent memory leaks, they are simply memory addresses.  Memory leaks are caused by dynamically allocating memory and failing to deallocate it; you are not using dynamic memory allocation (in the code presented), so memory leak is not an issue.  Besides dynamic memory allocation _requires_ pointers, so in that sense pointers can _cause_ leaks, not prevent them - but only through incorrect use;  _correct code_ prevents (or rather avoids) memory leaks.

Comment: @Clifford oh my bad for not using the concept well. I'll keep studying to learn more :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `==` is not for assignment. C is a pretty low level language you can not assign values to strings in C like you would for an integer or a character.

To do so you must use the standard library `string.h`.

For instance:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char source[1000], destination[1000];

    /* Do something with the strings */

    strcpy(destination, source);
    return 0;
}
```

Find out more about `string.h` [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/string.3.html)

Comment: Thanks it worked!

char operName[15];
/* ...  */

strcpy(operName, "ADD");

Comment: You are welcome; glade I could be of help.